# how to change the look of kendoUI splitter in the required format

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I am using kendoUI splitter.I want to change the splitter look some thing like splitter in 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349801(v=ws.10).aspx page.I have applied some styles like

```
 .k-splitter .k-splitbar-horizontal {
            width:5px;
     }
  .k-splitbar-horizontal .k-icon {
            top:5%;
     }
```

but it is not changed upto the mark.can anyone tell me how to change it in required format

Answer (score 2):

Replace first CSS definition by:

```
.k-splitter > .k-splitbar-horizontal {
    width:5px;
}
```

or:

```
.k-splitter .k-splitbar.k-splitbar-horizontal {
    width: 0px;
}
```

That should define the width of the splitter bar.

Comment: no change ,when I apply First one.If I apply second ,nothing is displaying

Comment: set `width: 50px` and see if it is wider. By the way, which version of Kendo UI are you using? Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Tkst9/